# declare function.Consumer<T> that can consume everything?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

In Java, are there any way to declare a Consumer that can be fed to any method requiring a specific Consumer?

I'll try to illustrate:

```
A createA(String someVar, Consumer<ThingAConfig> configLambda);
B createB(String someVar, Consumer<ThingBConfig> configLambda);

Consumer<?> NO_CONFIG = c -> {}

createA("", NO_CONFIG);  // does not work, "argument mismatch"
createB("", NO_CONFIG);  // does not work, "argument mismatch"
```

One thing that does work, is to make a raw Consumer:

```
Consumer RAW_NO_CONFIG = c -> {}
```

But then you get "unchecked conversion" upon usage.

```
createA("", RAW_NO_CONFIG);  // "works" with "unchecked conversion"
createB("", RAW_NO_CONFIG);  // "works" with "unchecked conversion"
```

It seems too strict to not be able to make something like that, as there are plenty of reasons why I would want a consumer that can eat anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the signature of `createA()` and `createB()`. they should be

```
A createA(String someVar, Consumer<? super ThingAConfig> configLambda);
```

That way, you'll be able to pass a `Consumer<ThingAConfig>`, or a `Consumer<Object>` (that can eat anything), or a consumer of any superclass or super-interface of `ThingAConfig`.

If you stick with `Consumer<ThingAConfig>` as argument type, then the only thing you can pass is a `Consumer<ThingAConfig>`.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! I was actually brushing up to that idea, but stupidly ended up thinking something like "oh, but then it could get an Object", so I didn't pursue it. But of course, "createA" would never provide an Object..! I still find these aspects of java's generics baffling: I, as the invoker of createA, should be the one deciding what I can handle with my Consumer.

Comment: Well, that is the case. If the consuler can accept any object, then use a Consumer<Object> and pass it as argument. No problem. If the consumer needs a ThingAConfig, then use a Consumer<ThingAConfig>, and pass it as argument. No Problem. But if the consuler needs a Banana, using a Consumer<Banana> won't cut it, because what createA() will give to the consumer is not a banana, it's a ThingAConfig.

Comment: Yes I understand those obvious things - which holds for the rest of the type system that Java has. The very non-obvious aspect is that I cannot send a Consumer<GenericConfig> (or <Object>)  to a method that requires Consumer<SpecificConfig> (without the super). The invoker of that method is the one that eventually will get that accept(T) call, and whether I want to accept it as a SpecificConfig, GenericConfig or Object should be up to me. I do understand that there are other issues/scenarios at hand that makes this non-straightforward. It seems like the JEP 10 will fix exactly those problems?

Comment: The problem is that Java doesn't know that ThingAConfig is only used in consuming methods of the Consumer. Suppose you pass a List<ThingAConfig>, which is both a consumer (add(ThingAConfig)) and a producer (ThingAConfig get()). Since createA would expect a List<ThingAConfig>, that can mean that createA() will get elements from the list, and that these elements must be T instances. So passing a List<Object> can't possibly work. Using List<? super ThingAConfig> tells the compiler that it will be used as a consumer. Using List<? extends ThingAConfig> tells that it will be used as a producer.

Answer (score 2):

Another work around is to call a method like this to get a Consumer of the needed type:

```
public static <T> Consumer<T> emptyConsumer(){
    return t -> {};
}
...
createA("", emptyConsumer());

//Of course you could also just do this in this case:
createA("", c -> {});
```

Or if you can wait for Java 10 there is a [JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8043488) open which will allow the creators of an interface or class to specify the wildcard for you, so your methods will be equivalent to the one in [JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844311/3179759).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping for some kind of workaround like this, but I wouldn't have found it myself. Thanks for the reference to the JEP, sounds smart to make this somewhat smoother.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this

```
A createA(String someVar, Consumer<?> configLambda)
```

Consumer can accept any type. We can limit it to an extent in following ways

```
A createA(String someVar, Consumer<? extends ParentType> configLambda)
//meaning passed type should be ParentType or child of ParentType

A createA(String someVar, Consumer<? super ChildType> configLambda)
//meaning passed type should be ChildType or some parent of ChildType
```

The other way to do it is

```
<T> A createA(String someVar, Consumer<T> configLambda)
```

In this case too it can accept any type, most of the time Java should be able to infer the type T by the type of the variable passed, if not you'll have to manually pass the type information.

```
//without explicit type
myClassObj.createA("", new Consumer<SomeType>);

//with explicit type
myClassObj.<SomeType>createA("", new Consumer<SomeType>);
```

Comment: That is incorrect: you can't pass anything to a `Consumer<? extends ParentType>`.

Comment: class ChildType extends ParentType{ }, Consumer<ChildType>, this will work.

Comment: But my point is that the createA method, receiving a Consumer<? extends ParentType> as argument, won't be able to pass anything to the accept() method of the consumer. So using a Consumer<? extends ParentType> makes no sense. It would make sense if it were a Supplier, providing things instead of consuming things. Read about PECS.